# coc.nvim throwing error on startup of nvim after update "E15: Invalid expression: exists('g:did_coc_loaded') || v:version < 800^M"

Tags: git, neovim, line-endings, coc.nvim

I don't know what happened here, but before I did 'PlugInstall' everything was fine.

now I'm getting this when starting up nvim:

```
Error detected while processing /home/rcrod/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/plugin/coc.vim:
line 2:
E15: Invalid expression: exists('g:did_coc_loaded') || v:version < 800^M
line 659:
E171: Missing :endif
```

*I did PlugInstall because I added devicons plugin. I also searched for this specific error but got me nothing.

don't know what's the problem, any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: That `^M` shouldn't be there. Did you clone the repository with Windows line-endings?

Comment: @romainl hmmm, I did the 'PlugInstall' in wsl (Ubuntu), also did autocrlf true but error's still there, not sure why it has the windows line-endings though,

Comment: yeah right there, the fault was setting autocrlf to true, setting it to false fixed it. thanks for the help @romainl!